# How to hide refferer from a website

Tags: javascript, php, html

For example I have a website X and I don't want the other site Y, to know my url adress if someone goes to site Y through my website X. How do I do that?

Comment: you can link to a data:URL that uses a script or meta tag to go to the destination. using data: as an intermediary strips any useful info from the http referral.

Answer (score 1):

There is `noreferrer` value for `rel` attribute:

https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/semantics.html#link-type-noreferrer
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Link_types

> Prevents the browser, when navigating to another page, to send this page name, or any other value, as referrer via the Referer: HTTP header.
>   (In Firefox, before Firefox 37, this worked only in links found in pages. Links clicked in the UI, like "Open in a new tab" via the contextual menu, ignored this).

Example:

```
 <a href="http://www.example.com" rel="noreferrer">example</a>
```

There is also a library that tries to support noreferrer on older/non-supportive browsers:

https://github.com/knu/noreferrer